# Can auto fields be added to existing address locator schemas?

Tags: geocoding, xml, address

There is a type of address locator that comes as part of RouteSmart for ArcGIS plug in. When this address locator is used to geocode it gives a match status field and a street ID field. Is it possible to duplicate these fields in the add locators schema but turn off the update behavior? I want to keep track of what doesn't automatically geocode and when a point is moved around the corner, which changes it's original link ID.

Thought maybe something like this?

```
<outputs>
                    <output component="Shape" type="geometry"/>
                    <output component="Status" candidate_mode="false" length="1"/>
                    <output component="Status2" #(I added this as a possible way to duplicate. Can I make a change here so it doesn't auto update)candidate_mode="false" length="1"/>
                    <output component="Score" type="float" decimal_digits="2"/>
                    <output component="Match_addr" length="120"/>
                    <output ref="House" batch_mode="false" length="12"/>
```